# Using cin.good for strings

Tags: c++

How do I make cin.good work on strings too?

[this is not a link]

```
while (1)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << "\n" << "Enter the state you are from" << endl;
        cin >> s;
        if (!cin.good())
        {
            cout << "\n" << "Please the enter the correct form of your state :)" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Even if I input a number instead of string, it still does not work.

Comment: `cin` can only fail to read a string if there's an I/O error or EOF before finding any (non-whitespace) text... in either case looping could go on infinitely, so it's probably best to `exit`.  Using an `is_valid_state(s))` function would be a better way to decide when to loop/break.

Comment: Suppose I input 1234,maybe you think I input a number,but I just input a string "1234". Please read Tony comment.

Comment: How is `s` declared?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the `if` condition.

> cin.good() returns 0 if it has a problem reading from the file, file not existing, etc

As said in the comments under your post, entering 1234 as integer would still be considered as "1234". I think the best way would be to iterate through each character to check if they are digit and if it reaches the end, then it is a number.

```
string::const_iterator it = str.begin();

while(it != str.end() && isdigit(*it))
{
    it++;
}

if (!str.empty() && it == str.end())
    cout << "not a string";
else
    cout << "valid";
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/gZkmQ0) is the link to the working example of the above code.

Comment: I used cin,fail(), still does not work. I'm just having hard time to print sth that satisfies the condition there.(If.....else) and make the loop work;

Answer (score 0):

> Even if I input a number instead of string, it still does not work

There is no such thing as "input a number instead of string".  The user doesn't have any control over the datatype, the code reads a string.

In case the user inputs a string which is a representation of a number, that is still a valid string, and `cin` will still be in a good state.

You could use (for example) `strtoi` on the string to see if it is a number.  But that is still very weak validation logic.  "C*7" is not a number, but probably you don't want to accept it as a state/province name either.  Apply some rules on what makes a valid name, and numeric inputs will be blocked along with all the other garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The job of `cin` is to get data. If it can't it will set flags like `.good()`, `.fail()`, `.eof`. You can check them, when needed. In this case it got a string. It doesn't matter if you like the string, or not.

It is up to the programmer to use other code to validate that the string is useful, for example by checking if the string matches a valid state. It is not up to `cin` to decide anything about the data after it is provided successfully. It is like blaming the phone for who the caller is.

If all the states are placed in an associative container: `set`/`unordered_set`/`map`/`unordered_map`, then the code could look something like the following:

```
string msg="Enter the state you are from";
while (cin.good()) // make sure there is more to do.
        {
            cout << "\n" << msg << endl;
            string s;            
            cin >> s;
            if (valid_states.contains(s)) {
                break;
            } else {
                msg="Please the enter the correct form of your state :)" << endl;
            }
        }
```

It is the container that is being used to check if the state is valid.